# Visual Studio - Cannot start Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, android-sdk-manager

I've done an update on SDK Manager and after restarting Visual Studio I cannot launch anything related to Xamarin Android

```
[I:sdk]:                  Looking for Android SDK..
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path does not contain adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\android-sdk-windows).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\MonoAndroid\PrivateAndroidSdkPath not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path found:
    Path contains adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]:                  Looking for Android NDK..
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack.exe in \. (C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Android\ndk\android-ndk-r10e).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]:                  Looking for Java 6 SDK..
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\CurrentVersion found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6\JavaHome not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.7\JavaHome found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71).
[I:Unknown]:              Found Xamarin.Android 6.0.3
[I:Unknown]:              Found Android SDK. API levels: 15, 17, 19, 23
```

What should I do  please.... kind of desperate..

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of Android-SDK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if Visual Studio is pointing to the correct Android SDK location by Clicking on Tools > Option

[image]

If not you can change it to the correct location and try re-strating Visual Studio